# How to send only certain inputs to the next layer based on label value

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Label y can take 0 or 1 value. I want to pass the input features to the next layer only if the corresponding data point has y value equal to 1. How would I implement this in tensorflow?

If I were to add a custom activation function, how would I take the y value(label) as an input to it? Another option was to use masks but I'm not too familiar with the syntax can someone please guide

Answer (score 0):

You could do this either by creating a layer specifically for it, something like

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class Conditional_Layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Conditional_Layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, labels):
        # if y is 1, else pass zeros
        return tf.where(tf.equal(labels, 1), inputs, tf.zeros_like(inputs))

# going through your model
in_features = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(feature_shape,)) # where feature_shape is the dimensions of the data
in_labels = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

conditional_layer = Conditional_Layer()([in_features, in_labels])
```

Or by using a mask

```py
mask = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_train, 1), dtype=tf.float32) # anywhere y==1, else set to 0
masked_input = x_train * mask
out = model(masked_input) # send through the rest of the model
```

The layer could be slotted into a network easily, while the mask may be better for intermediate results. Be cautious when doing this, however, especially when training, as this masking will largely affect the flow of your gradient during backprop.

Comment: So since the layer takes in two inputs, the model will also need to append that to inputs right? model = Model(inputs=[in_features,in_labels], outputs=[output]). How will the model.fit() look in this case? Would it have to be passed like this : model.fit(x=[x_train, y_train],y=y_train,epochs=10, batch_size=32)?                     Also one minor correction is that since the layer takes two input parameters, shouldn't they be passed as two parameters and not one list, in this manner : conditional_layer = Conditional_Layer()(in_features, in_labels)

Comment: Further, how would I remove this while testing? I want the model to be trained using all these functionalities but during the testing phase, I want the model to only take in the x_test

Comment: Right, I was mostly just demonstrating how one _could_ do this. Regarding passing in to inputs, you're right I wouldn't do that. If one chooses to do this, you could pass in `in_labels` as an array of nulls and check for this in the conditional layer. I do think masking however is the better approach.